# Javascript Change image on click

Tags: javascript

I have a some images

```
<img src="hey.png" alt=""/><img src="asf.png" alt=""/><img src="3.png" alt=""/><img src="4.png" alt=""/>
```

How to make sure that when you click on the picture - these 4 images were interchanged arbitrarily (random)?

Comment: What do you mean? do you want to shuffle all those images when one of them is clicked?

Comment: Or do you want to display one image, and swap it to another one of the 4 when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm:

- grab the dom elements for the images and put them in an array
- shuffle the array
- remove them from the page
- put them back on the page in the newly shuffled order.

Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That's not really an answer, now is it?

Answer (score 0):

Choose a `random number` and exchange the source of the `image` with the first image and then replace the src of other two  images

Eg to get select index of random image

```
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
```

You can access the source of image by using

```
document.getElementById("ImageId").src = "Image source"
```